# WebClient on WP7 - Throw "A request with this method cannot have a request body"

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient

If I execute this code in a Consoleapp it works fine:

```
        string uriString = "http://url.com/api/v1.0/d/" + Username + "/some?amount=3&offset=0";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers["Authorization"] = AuthString.Replace("\\", "");

        string responseArrayKvitteringer = wc.DownloadString(uriString);
        Console.WriteLine(responseArrayKvitteringer);
```

But if I move the code to my WP7 project like this:

```
        string uriString = "http://url.com/api/v1.0/d/" + Username + "/some?amount=3&offset=0";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            wc.Headers["Authorization"] = AuthString.Replace("\\", "");

            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uriString));

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

I got the exception: A request with this method cannot have a request body.

Why?

The solution is to remove the Content-type:

```
   string uriString = "http://url.com/api/v1.0/d/" + Username + "/some?amount=3&offset=0";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            //wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            wc.Headers["Authorization"] = AuthString.Replace("\\", "");

            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uriString));

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

Comment: For various reasons and many more(!), I'd suggest you that you try to use the WebRequest instead of the WebClient wrapper... there are some "tricks" that the WebClient does that my be causing this issue, and WebRequest gives you a greater control over the Http comunication!

Comment: Hi Pedro. I already tried that. It gives my the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why Console is not throwing, but you are essentially using the wrong header.

Content-Type on a request denotes the content of the POST/PUT data (the body of the HTTP request). What you want is the Accept header.

```
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287673(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: Also, though unrelated, Pedro's suggestion is very good. First thing I did was create my own WebClient wrapper - using WebRequest. It's much easier to debug and also gives you more control over what you do in the UI.

Comment: You're right. The solution with Accept in the header is working. The solution with only Authorization in the header is also working. Thanks.